# "I’m afraid that they will call me when I will be doing my homework" Is that correct?

Tags: future, continuous-aspect

dear stackexchangers, need your help.

As you sure know there is a rule about using Present Simple instead of Future Simple after words "when", "before", "if", etc. But what about my sentence? Can we use Future Continuos after "WHEN"? My sentence seems logical to me.

Thanks for considering my request :)

Comment: The usual form is "...they will call when I am doing my homework." But you could say "I'm afraid when they call I will be doing my homework". But there are certainly circumstances where you can use the future tense after "when/if". e.g. "I don't know when/if they will come".

Comment: or use "while I'm doing" instead of "when I will be doing".

Comment: If you use _will_ in the first clause, and it's clear the second clause is simultaneous with the first clause, there's no need to repeat the modal.

Answer (score 1):

I think that “when I am doing my homework” sounds fine, but I would personally use “WHILE I am doing my homework.”